# Adding several strings to a layout

Tags: android, list, layout, textview, scrollview

I need to add some strings to my layout, but I need to add each string in a new line (as a list) and make the layout scrollable when it exceeds the vertical dimension. The amount of these strings is defined at runtime so I do like this:

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
LinearLayout scrollViewLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
scrollViewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv2;

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { //count is defined at runtime when the
                                 //array strings[] is created
                                 //and defines the amount of array's values
    tv2 = new TextView(context);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tv2.setText(strings[i]);
    scrollViewLayout.addView(tv2);
}

scrollView.addView(scrollViewLayout);
```

But I don't think that instantiating objects in a loop and adding strings like this is acceptable, moreover, I get log messages "GC_FOR_ALLOC..." and "Grow heap..." because of that `ScrollView` object so I think I should perform this action in another, more appropriate way. Please explain me how to correctly add strings to a layout and make it scrollable. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use one `TextView` and append text to it in each loop iteration. Something like

```
TextView tv2;
tv2 = new TextView(context);
tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { //count is defined at runtime when the
                             //array strings[] is created
                             //and defines the amount of array's values
    if (i > 0)
        tv2.append(" \n" + strings[i]);
    else
        tv2.setText(strings[i]);
}
scrollView.addView(scrollViewLayout);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\n` instead of `/n`?

Comment: Well, I just thought that using the same `TextView` object a lot of times would end up in an error or it is not acceptable. So you say my code is good? But maybe there's still a way to avoid using `ScrollView`? Because I get those errors if instantiating it...

Comment: You haven't said anything about errors. No, I think ScrollView is fine but the way I have shown you will only be instantiating one TextView one time. All you are doing is adding a newline character and new text each time through the loop.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to make so I can't tell you the "best" way but from what you have so far, this is how I would do it.

Comment: Saying 'errors' I mean  "GC_FOR_ALLOC..." and "Grow heap...".

Comment: No, you aren't getting errors then. But using one TextView will probably be better for what you are doing. Give this a try

Comment: So those messages doesn't mean that something is wrong even if they say that it's allocating around 12 MB of memory for this task?

Comment: It has to allocate more memory because you are creating multiple `TextView`s

Comment: I accepted your answer because it is more comprehensive. Thank you very much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50650/discussion-between-salivan-and-codemagic)

Comment: Ok, that is always entirely up to you. I'm glad we could help. Both were correct and good in their own right. uDevel got an upvote anyway for removing the (probably) unnecessary `LinearLayout` which I didn't take the time to do ;)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you can't use the same TextView again and again?

For example:

```
tv2.setText(tv2.getText() + *newline* + msg);
```

In your case:

```
for(String str : strings)
{
     tv2.setText(tv2.getText() + *newline* + str);
}
```

Comment: Well, I just thought that using the same `TextView` object a lot of times would end up in an error or it is not acceptable. So you say my code is good? But maybe there's still a way to avoid using `ScrollView`? Because I get those errors if instantiating it...

Comment: Did you mean "GC_FOR_ALLOC" when you say errors?
Those are not errors, those just mean it needs more memory.

Comment: But it says it's allocating around 12 MB of memory. Isn't it too much for an action that just adds like 15 lines of text?

Comment: You need to use scrollview if you want to be able to scroll.  Well, Listview can be use since it's a scrollview too, but why make it complicated.

My code there is the most simple it can get.  
You don't even need the linearlayout.
Just put textview in scrollview.

Comment: Try my code first and compare.
Having 1 textview is much better than having 15 textview.

Comment: Okay. You and codeMagic both answered approximately the same so whose answer should I mark as acceptable?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as we helped you.
Maybe whoever answer first?

Comment: I accepted codeMagic's answer because it is more comprehensive but I want to say a big thanks to you for explaining that those messages in a log aren't errors and that I don't need a layout. Big thanks!